# In Sql, group on Column , but not show in all rows

Tags: sql

I am working on a query in database. Say i have a patient which travelled to 3 hospitals. Now i want to add the cost of his journey but want to show it only at his first journey ,the total cost.

file right now is like

```
Patient Hospital1  cost
A         1        200
A         2        400
A         3        100
B         1        200
```

I want the output as

```
Patient Hosptial      Cost
A         1           700
A         2
A         3
B         1           200
```

Thanks

Comment: Will it always be hospital 1, 2, 3, etc? Or can it be gaps, duplicates, another start number etc?

Comment: Building on jarl's question - you need a way to identify which journey is the first one.  Whether it be 'Hospital 1 is always first in the journey', or a date column that clarifies which is first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have build this 1,2,3 of patient journey on their ED arrival and time. so there will be no gaps and duplicates or another start number. it will always start with 1 and will be in sequence. But that part is sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by patient order by hospital1) = 1
             then sum(cost) over (partition by patient)
        end) as total_cost
from t
order by patient, hospital1;
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE MyTable(Patient varchar(20),Hospital int, Cost int)
> INSERT INTO MyTable(Patient,Hospital,Cost) VALUES ('A',1,200),('A',2,400),
> ('A',3,100),
> ('B',1,200)
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (SELECT Patient,SUM(Cost) AS Cost FROM MyTable
> GROUP BY Patient)
>
> SELECT M.Patient,M.Hospital,
> CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY M.Patient ORDER BY M.Hospital)=1 THEN CAST(C.Cost AS VARCHAR(255))
> ELSE '' END AS Cost FROM CTE AS C
> INNER JOIN Mytable AS M ON C.Patient=M.Patient
> ```

> ```
> Patient | Hospital | Cost
> :------ | -------: | :---
> A       |        1 | 700 
> A       |        2 |     
> A       |        3 |     
> B       |        1 | 200
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ce7a433c3bfae60dd4d364cd72b43dcb)*

Answer (score 0):

If you had the records in a table, called PatientVisits, with the following data:

[image]

You could use this query:

```
SELECT PV.Patient, PV.Hospital, PVGroup.TotalCost
FROM PatientVisits PV
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT Patient, MIN(Hospital) as FirstVisit, SUM(Cost) as TotalCost
FROM PatientVisits
GROUP BY Patient) PVGroup ON
PV.Patient = PVGroup.Patient AND
PV.Hospital = PVGroup.FirstVisit
ORDER BY PV.Patient, PV.Hospital
```

The results would be:

[image]

Comment: Hi MDiesel, didnt think the query this way. Thankyou so much. Very kind of you.

Comment: @paru80 happy to help!  Let me know if you have any questions